# Baking and a rotten egg was cracked into mix :(

Tags: baking, food-safety, eggs

I was mixing together my batter for gluten free cinnamon rolls (aka- using really expensive flour!), I broke an egg into the mix and the yolk looked almost like it was hard boiled... it had not been! The white looked normal. I immediately took it out as best I could (got all the yolk for sure, but I’m sure some white remained). Is my entire batch no good? It will be baked at 350 for 45 minutes, does that make a difference?

Comment: Is it possible your eggs were frozen?

Comment: Did it smell rotten?

Comment: Maybe your egg wasn't super-fresh but if it wasn't smelling rotten, probably wasn't

Comment: That is why grandmothers always tell you to crack eggs into a separate bowl. You never knew how a store-bought egg was going to turn out 50 years ago. It's still good advice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the whole batch is unusable. Baking doesn't change anything, food safety rules don't foresee turning unsafe food back into safe.